# how to access member of outer class from inner class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

How to access the member of outer class from member function of inner class in kotlin. Consider the following code.

```
class A{
    var name: String

    class B{
        fun show(){
            print(name)          //<----- here ide shows error. name is not accessible
        }
    }
}
```

I am writing this code in android studio. It is working when written in java but not when we write code in kotlin.

Comment: make it as **internal** variable.

Comment: `B` is not a _child_ class or a subclass as in the title, it's a _nested_ class. In Java nested classes are inner by default; in Kotlin they aren't.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should mark `class B` as `inner`:

```
class A{
  var name: String

  inner class B{
    fun show(){
      print(name)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
class A{
lateinit var name: String

inner class B{
    fun show(){
        print(name)
    }
}
}
```